# chassan/kallah signing the kesubah or tenaaim

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, names, wedding, legal-documents

I have seen bridegrooms and brides sign their names on their [kesuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketubah) or tenaaim (prenup) before the [chuppah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuppah) (wedding ceremony). It seems maybe to be a [chassidish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasidic_Judaism) custom, though I'm not sure.

Is there a source for this, and, if so, what's the reason?

Comment: Rav Moshe Tendler shlit"a, I believe following the view of his father-in-law Rav Moshe Feinstein, has both bride and groom sign an English version of the kesuba so that it should presumably be binding as a prenup in a secular court as well.

Comment: (also, not that it necessarily detracts from his answer, but I believe the "Rabbi" who answered your question may have been recently outed as a disguised missionary who infiltrated the chareidi community in Israel)

Comment: https://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/304995  https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20210427-israel-group-exposes-rabbi-as-christian-missionary/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know that it is necessarily a Chassidish custom, but it is an Israeli one.  Some sources include Orchas Mishpat 1.  Yabia Omer 3 Even HaEzer 13,  Trumas HaDeshen 2:232, Rashba on Bava Basra 175a and [Nahar Mitzrayim 192b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34123&st=&pgnum=56).

According to Rav Ovadiah Yosef who sums up most of these sources in his responsa in Yabia Omer the reason to to halakhically strengthen the grooms responsibility to pay his Ketubah including the added sum, as well as to make the contract legally binding in a civil court.

As far as the bride signing, I have not heard of that.

Comment: Thanks for info,don't know why she would also sign.

Comment: Chassidim have make a separate ceremony (at or right after engagement) where both groom and bride sign, thereby obligating themselves to marry each other.

Comment: Please be aware that the author of this answer, "Michael Tzadok," has recently been [outed as a Christian missionary](https://www.northjersey.com/story/news/new-jersey/2021/05/03/orthodox-rabbi-nj-accused-double-life-missionary-israel/4868837001/). His real name is Michael Elk. Please also see [here](https://youtu.be/8N6sPqFBt3A) and [here](https://youtu.be/8g71VZrjCpg).