# Why was a wedding in Jerusalem conducted differently to in the UK?

Tags: minhag, wedding, edim-witnesses

At a recent wedding in Jerusalem, I noticed the following differences from the practice I have got used to in the UK. *(I realise this question could be asked to justify UK custom in the face of the custom in Jerusalem; please allow it in this form).*

My questions are (1) whether these differences are special only to Jerusalem or whether they exist elsewhere and (2) the sources of the differences and if any reasons are given for them.

Difference 1: cup is broken after the 'erusin' blessings and before the seven blessings of 'nisuim'. *(In the UK after the seven blessings of 'nisuin'.)*

Difference 2: Witnesses sign the kesuboh under the chupah after it has been read up to where they should sign. *(In the UK before the chupah.)*

Difference 3: The Chosson signs the kesuboh. *(In the UK he does not sign.)*

Comment: In the United Synagogue of the UK both choson and Kalla sign. They also dont allow proper music in Yerusholaim.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28799/759

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35822/759

Comment: Actually, the chosson signing the kesubah isn't ONLY a Sephardi minhag, it's a minhag Yirushalayim. Rav Kook, for instance, ruled that the Chosson sign for even Ashkenazi weddings in Yirushalayim.

Comment: The chosson signing the Kesubah isn't only Sefardi or Yirushalayim. I've seen it done at a Yekkish wedding as well (apparently that was the custom of the place).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen #2 and #3 at Sephardic weddings outside of Israel (I believe the officiating rabbi was of Algerian ancestry) as well. So I'd assume it's more of an Ashkenazic/Sephardic split than a Jerusalem/UK split, though it's certainly possible that Sephardic practice influences non-Sephardim in Jerusalem as well.

Comment: I've signed a Ketuba as a witness under the chuppah at an Ashkenazic wedding in NY.

Comment: Yeah the typical Sephardic Minhag is to sign under the Chuppah. If you're real old school you would have the Kethubbah WRITTEN on the day of the wedding after much arguing.

Answer (score 0):

The signing on the kesuboh by the Chosson is a Sepharadic Minhag but even for Sepharadim it is not mandatory and even if he did not sign, it is perfectly Kosher (providing of course that it complies with all other aspects of the Halacha).

Regarding the glass breaking, in both cases, it occurs during the Chupa which means the Nisuim is already valid.